# UIView Subclass backed by xib with Size Classes wrong frame

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, autolayout, interface-builder, size-classes

I am working on a project for `iOS 7.0+` with a storyboard, using `Size Classes` with `AutoLayout` and I'm using a `UIView` subclass backed by a `xib` file of the same name.

What I'am trying to do is I'am instantiating a `UIView` from `xib` programmatically and adding it to a `ViewController` from a Storyboard. This `ViewController` has `AutoLayout` up and running but the `UIView` I am adding doesn't respect the frame of the `ViewController`.

I'm instantiating my `UIView` subclass like this:

```
 tabBarView = [[SHDTabBarView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.height-50, self.view.width, 50)];
 [self.view addSubview:tabBarView];
```

And inside the subclass I'm using a set up of creating a `UIView` `IBOutlet` called `container` to instantiate it form code like this:

```
 -(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
 self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
 if (self == nil) return nil;
 [self initalizeSubviews];
 return self;
 }

 -(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
 self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
 if (self == nil) return nil;
 [self initalizeSubviews];
 return self;
 }

 -(void)initalizeSubviews{
 NSString *nibName = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
 UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
 [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
 //Add the view loaded from the nib into self.
 [self addSubview:self.container];
 }
```

This is how my `xib` looks in the Interface Builder (notice the width of the canvas is 320 px):

[image]

And that's how it looks on the iPhone 6 (notice how it's getting cut off from the right side):

[image]

I've tried to use a multitude of solutions, including doing it all in code with an open-source solution [PureLayout](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout), using a manual constraint set up, etc.

None of my findings seem to work right. Ideally, I want to set up everything in `Interface Builder`, then just add the view to the superview of the `ViewController` with according frame and let `AutoLayout` do its magic.

How should I approach this task? Any advices are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the frame of your subview in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. Looks like you init your subview before view fully layouted